# How to get number of workers available in ProcessPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, proc

I am running some cpu bound code inside an async function, using `ProcessPoolExecutor`

```
pool = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(10)
...
loop.run_in_executor(
            pool, cpu_bound_func)
```

**How do I get the number of workers available to be used?**

Answer (score 0):

The [Python docs for `ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) say that *"If max_workers is None or not given, it will default to the number of processors on the machine."*

If we peek under the hood, we can see that `ProcessPoolExecutor` uses `os.cpu_count()` to determine the number of workers to use (`self._max_workers = os.cpu_count() or 1`). So one way of getting the number of workers is to do the following (not recommended since the implementation of `_max_workers` could change in the future):

```py
pool = ProcessPoolExecutor()
print(pool._max_workers)
```

If you need this information before creating the pool, you can use `os.cpu_count()` directly:

```py
import os
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

actual_cpu_count = os.cpu_count()
desired_cpu_count = actual_cpu_count - 1  # for example
pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(desired_cpu_count)
```

Comment: I want to check how many workers are currently being used, and how many are available to be used. Is there an API for that?